# Xarray-Spatial and Poetry compatibility

Tags: python-poetry

I'm trying to install xarray-spatial via `poetry` on Ubuntu 22.04, below the simple `.toml` with which I've tried to install the library:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "xarray-spatial-test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = []
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "xarray_spatial"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When I use `poetry add xarray-spatial` I see the error below:

```
Using version ^0.3.5 for xarray-spatial

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.0s)

  AssertionError

  

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/mixology/incompatibility.py:113 in __str__
      109│         )
      110│ 
      111│     def __str__(self) -> str:
      112│         if isinstance(self._cause, DependencyCause):
    → 113│             assert len(self._terms) == 2
      114│ 
      115│             depender = self._terms[0]
      116│             dependee = self._terms[1]
      117│             assert depender.is_positive()
```

This is strange because I've already used it withouth problems but on Ubuntu 20.04. This is also strange because I can install whitouth problems using `pip3 install xarray-spatial` in a test environment(`python3 -m venv test_env`) and if i use `xrspatial examples` I can downloads the examples.

Is there a compatibility problem between Poetry and xarray-spatial?

**NB: I can't add the tag `xarray-spatial`, if someone can please add it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error above is that `xarray-spatial` should be added under the `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` section of `pyproject.toml` rather than in the `packages` section.

Removing `{include = "xarray_spatial"}` from the above file and running `poetry add xarray-spatial` from your project will update `pyproject.toml` with the correct version of the package for your project.